# How to do multiple select operations in this case?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have been provided with following relational schema -

```
country (countrycode,name,capital) &
population (populationcode,population,countrycode)
```

Where countrycode is the foreign key w.r.t. relation country. I have to project the country with maximum population but aggregation operation  `MAX(population)` isn't directly working for the given command -.

```
SELECT pcode, ccode, name, capital
FROM population NATURAL JOIN country
WHERE ((SELECT MAX(population) as maxpopulation FROM population NATURAL JOIN country))
```

for the given set of data -

```
INSERT INTO country VALUES(1,'INDIA','NEW DELHI');
INSERT INTO country VALUES(2,'U.S.A.','WASHINGTON DC');
INSERT INTO country VALUES(3,'U.K.','LONDON');
INSERT INTO country VALUES(4,'CHINA','BEIJING');
INSERT INTO country VALUES(5,'JAPAN','TOKYO');

INSERT INTO population VALUES(1,1200000000,1);
INSERT INTO population VALUES(2,350000000,2);
INSERT INTO population VALUES(3,65640000,3);
INSERT INTO population VALUES(4,1300000000,4);
INSERT INTO population VALUES(5,127000000,5);
```

As it is producing the following output in the terminal -

```
+-------+-------+--------+---------------+
| pcode | ccode | name   | capital       |
+-------+-------+--------+---------------+
|     1 |     1 | INDIA  | NEW DELHI     |
|     2 |     2 | U.S.A. | WASHINGTON DC |
|     3 |     3 | U.K.   | LONDON        |
|     4 |     4 | CHINA  | BEIJING       |
|     5 |     5 | JAPAN  | TOKYO         |
+-------+-------+--------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the expected output is -

```
+-------+-------+--------+---------------+
| pcode | ccode | name   | capital       |
+-------+-------+--------+---------------+
|     4 |     4 | CHINA  | BEIJING       |
+-------+-------+--------+---------------+
1 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But it should only tell attributes of country with maximum population which is china.

So what kind of operation could be performed ?

Comment: Forget about the NATURAL JOIN construction, specify the join conditions!!!

Comment: Specify the expected result as well! (BTW, you need a correlated sub-query.)

Comment: @jarlh I added the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:

```
SELECT pcode, ccode, name, capital
FROM population NATURAL JOIN country
WHERE population = (SELECT MAX(population) FROM population)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer it worked . I didn't knew that I had to use population = (SELECT .... ) After WHERE. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `NATURAL JOIN`.  It is an abomination, because it uses keys that have the same *names*.  It does not even use properly declared foreign key relationships.

If you are looking for only one row, then I would recommend `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
select p.populationcode, p.countrycode, c.name, c.capital
from population p join
     country c
     using (countrycode)  -- of course, the traditional explicit "on" is totally correct too
order by p.population desc
limit 1;
```

When you use the version comparing maximum populations, then you can get duplicates.  If that is what you want, then definitely use that version.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub query in your `WHERE` and use the `LIMIT` function.

```
SELECT p.populationcode, c.countrycode, c.name, c.capital
FROM population p
INNER JOIN country c ON p.countrycode = c.countrycode
WHERE (SELECT countrycode 
       FROM (SELECT countrycode, population 
             FROM population 
             ORDER BY population DESC LIMIT 1)) = c.countrycode
```